# pdf download - safari

Tags: html, safari

I have a link on my webpage that will allow the user to download a pdf file.

HTML

```
<a href="assets/downloads/MeadowPack/Pack3.pdf" download>Pack 3 - Wildflowers</a>
```

This is all fine for FF, Chrome and IE but the download attribute is not supported by Safari. Is there another option I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I just find this solution.
[Using the HTML5 Download Attribute](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/using-the-html5-download-attribute.html#fbid=OXPwTO3t6Sm)